# input form data into database through php

Tags: php, html, sql

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. The data is not getting stored in phpmyadmin. may be its a syntax error.I ll be glad if someone could find the problem with my code. Please help me out on this!

It is a simple form asking for the details of the person who needs blood. I need the details to be stored into the database named 'blood_share_system' and the table name 'acceptors'.

**my html file:**

```
<form action="needblood.inc.php"method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
            <label>FirstName</label><br>
              <input type="text"name="first"required><br>
            <label>LastName</label><br>
              <input type="text"name="last"required><br>
            <label>PatientFirstName</label><br>
              <input type="text"name="pfirst" required><br> 
              <lable>PatientLastName</label><br>
              <input type="text"name="plast"<br>

        </legend>
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>
        <lable>Phone Number</label><br>
        <input type="tel"placeholder="10-digit PhoneNumber"name="phno" required><br>
        <lable>Email Address</label><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Valid email address"name="email"><br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>   
           <legend>Blood Group Information</legend>
           <label>Blood Group</label><br>
            <select name="bgroup">
                <option value="1">O-positive</option>
                <option value="2">O-negative</option>
                <option value="3">A-positive</option>
                <option value="4">A-negative</option>
                <option value="5">B-positive</option>
                <option value="6">B-negative</option>
                <option value="7">AB-positive</option>
                <option value="8">AB-negative</option>
             </select><br>
            <label>Quantity required(1Unit:350ml):</label><br>
            <button  class="nbtn"id="snbtn"onclick="nbuttonClick()">-</button>
        <input type="number" readonly="true" id="inc" value="0"name="quantity"required>
        <button class="pbtn"id="sbtn"onclick="buttonClick()">+</button>Unit</h4><br>
        <input type="number" id="result">ml
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Location Details</legend>
        <label>Locality</lable><br>
        <input type="text"name="loc"required><br>
        <label>Pincode</label><br>
        <input type="number"name="pincode"required>
    </fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit">
</form>
```

**my php file:**

```
<?php
//first if
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $dbserverName = "localhost";
    $dbuserName = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "blood_share_system";

    $conn = mysqli_connect( $dbserverName , $dbuserName , $dbpassword , $dbname);

    //2nd if
    if(!$conn){
        echo "connection was not established with server";
    }//2nd if close

    //3rd if
    if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'blood_share_system')){
        echo "not connected to the database";
    }//3rd if close

    $first=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['first']);
    $last=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['last']);
    $pfirst=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pfirst']);
    $plast=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['plast']);
    $phno=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phno']);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $bgroup=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['bgroup']);
    $quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['quantity']);
    $locality=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['loc']);
    $pincode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pincode']);

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" , $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" , $last)||!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" , $pfirst)||!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" , $plast) ){
        trigger_error('Enter valid names!',E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $phno)){
            trigger_error('Enter 10 digit phone number!');
        } else{
            if (!filter_var( $email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )){
                trigger_error('Enter valid email address!',E_USER_ERROR);
            } else{
                if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{6}$/", $pincode)){
                    trigger_error('Enter valid pincode!',E_USER_ERROR);
                } else {
                    $sql="INSERT INTO acceptors('$first','$last','$pfirst','$plast','$phno','$email','$bgroup','$quantity','$locality','$pincode');";
                    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                        echo "Not inserted";
                    } else {
                        echo"Inserted";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error message like invalid csrf token?

Comment: trigger_error.. check your error log, whats it say?

Comment: After initializing $sql echo it to get the SQL query as a string. Once you have it you can execute the query in phpmyadmin to get the error.

Comment: Looking at the SQL query, I can think of a possiblity that you have either misplaced the column values or haven't assigned  values for all the columns. It is always safe to use "insert into values" statements that simple "insert into" statement.

Comment: Try removing all the ifs and jump straight for the insert without checking any preg_match, see if that works, then if it does, add each if with the validation, one by one.

Also, avoid nesting if/else statements... it makes it really hard to read and maintain your code. I suggest using them after each one, and returning an error in case anything is broken.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you please tell me where do i check that?

Comment: @Rafael I tried that as well by bringing the query to the top and commenting out the rest...nothings working!

Comment: @Gabriel no such error

Comment: is there something i am missing here....because i have checked it so many times and i think its something trivial or something that i am totally not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible cause is use of **insert into** statement instead of **insert into... values** statement.

If you are using **insert into** statement, then you need to provide all the column values in the correct order of the columns.

Comment: but here i am inserting an entire row considering all attributes except the primary key....shouldn't that be okay?

Comment: or could it be due to any type mismatch in the database. Everything is varchar except for blood_quantity and pincode and id.

Comment: That's the case, when using `insert into` statement you can not assume anything and so you need to use null as placeholder for you primary key. It doesn't matter even if your primary key is auto-incremental, using null as placeholder does the trick. But as a good practice one should stick to `insert into... values` statement.

Comment: In this case there is no need to worry about datatype, quoted integers are implicitly converted into integers while inserting/updating into database.

Comment: okay I tried the alternate insert into statement as well...nothing changed...is there any other criteria that i have to verify excluding the syntax? I have created the database with the same name, as well as the table, apache server and sql is started as well.

Comment: Check my first comment about echoing the SQL statement string. Does it give any error or output?

Comment: I finally realised it was the path problem....my php file was  in a folder within the main folder and I never mentioned it in the action attribute of my html form tag. I echoed the sql statement as well....the query showed error in myadmin. I will work it out. Thanks a lot!